# MySql how to select all the questions and its answers from one table

Tags: mysql

My table structure is :( I surppose q stand for question and a for answer for only describe what it was,the id and parent_id are both INT type,id was auto_increment)

```
id title parent_id 
q1 ****  0( 0 means it was a question)
a2 ****  q1
a3 ****  q1
q4 ****  0
q5 ****  0
a6 ****  q4
a7 ****  q1
...
```

And at the admin page I want them to list in Question followed by its Answers.Just like:

```
Qustion1:****
Answer2: ****
Answer3: ****
Answer7: ****

Question4:****
Answer6: ****

Question5:****
Answer:none
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe use NULL instead of 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest answer:

```
SELECT * from qa
ORDER BY case parent_id when 0 then id else parent_id end, id
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b964/2).

Comment: that's great i never knew we can use a condition in order by. +1 for that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    (
        (SELECT 
            *
         FROM qa AS q
         WHERE q.parent_id = 0
         ORDER BY q.id 
         )
UNION ALL 
        (SELECT 
            *
         FROM qa AS q
         WHERE q.parent_id <> 0
         ORDER BY a.id)
) AS r
ORDER BY id , parent_id
```

### See SQL Fiddle Demo Here

OUTPUT

```
| ID | TITLE | PARENT_ID |
--------------------------
|  1 |    Q1 |         0 |
|  2 |    A1 |         1 |
|  3 |    A2 |         1 |
|  4 |    A3 |         1 |
|  5 |    A4 |         1 |
|  6 |    Q2 |         0 |
|  7 |    A1 |         6 |
|  8 |    A2 |         6 |
|  9 |    A3 |         6 |
| 10 |    A4 |         6 |
| 11 |    Q3 |         0 |
| 12 |    A1 |        11 |
| 13 |    A2 |        11 |
| 14 |    A3 |        11 |
| 15 |    A4 |        11 |
```

EDITED :

You can use Mark Bannister answer with IF condition too

```
SELECT 
    * 
from qa
ORDER BY IF(parent_id = 0 ,id ,parent_id ) , id
```